# Pegando uma string json

Tags: c#, json

Estou com dúvidas estou consultando uma api e ela me retorna isso:

```
"{\"optimized\": null, \"optimized_slo\": null, \"normal_slo\": {}, \"normal\": {\"estimated_cost\": \"28.40\", \"distance\": 10198, \"original_eta\": 2236, \"path_suggested_gencoded\": \"tiynClnx{GmBzBwAxCkDfEwAbBlEvExKjL~EfFlCpCiAxAwAhBsAhBmA`BqGfKSd@mA~Cy@xBqA`AYN^h@hBhCzAxBPZpAvCdAbC|JrUhKdVtC|GnArCJPNTvEzKjAvCNjANzA`@zH?ZCPPhDJbBHx@Hf@Fr@FpBl@rKFfATrDVzBLrAP|DRxDGb@Mh@Kp@?v@B`@D^d@tBj@lB^bAnAhDBp@El@y@rDaBtHJbBJt@ThApA|H|@`Gl@rCd@lBr@vCRfA\\\\rAd@tAxAxDf@|@~AxBP\\\\Pb@Lp@FbAKlCMjCDv@Jd@Xn@`DrFh@pAZxAjCdOfBdGbBpFf@x@TT^Rh@RpAXv@P\\\\L\\\\TZ^Vj@b@nAhBvFlCzHz@`Cj@bAt@rAfA~Bv@tBN`@Bb@@LR`AtAjGTbChA|C\\\\|@J^D`@Dv@@jAWxQMpG@bBXvCJfAc@GwFaC}BuAe@WOEUC\"}}"
```

e eu queria pegar por exemplo "Normal_SLO : estimated_cost : 28.40" e "Normal : estimated_cost : 20.40"  nesse exemplo que usei aparece só o slo mas tem casos que aparece 2 preços distintos, queria saber como eu poderia pegar esses valores sendo que a posição deles não é fixa.

Código usado para pegar os valores:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                   //o texto que estou pegando está armazenado nessa variavel responseText
                    var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();

                return true;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá.

Usando o Newtonsoft.Json, podes fazer o seguinte:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "{\"optimized\": null, \"optimized_slo\": null, \"normal_slo\": {}, \"normal\": {\"estimated_cost\": \"28.40\", \"distance\": 10198, \"original_eta\": 2236, \"path_suggested_gencoded\": \"tiynClnx{GmBzBwAxCkDfEwAbBlEvExKjL~EfFlCpCiAxAwAhBsAhBmA`BqGfKSd@mA~Cy@xBqA`AYN^h@hBhCzAxBPZpAvCdAbC|JrUhKdVtC|GnArCJPNTvEzKjAvCNjANzA`@zH?ZCPPhDJbBHx@Hf@Fr@FpBl@rKFfATrDVzBLrAP|DRxDGb@Mh@Kp@?v@B`@D^d@tBj@lB^bAnAhDBp@El@y@rDaBtHJbBJt@ThApA|H|@`Gl@rCd@lBr@vCRfA\\\\rAd@tAxAxDf@|@~AxBP\\\\Pb@Lp@FbAKlCMjCDv@Jd@Xn@`DrFh@pAZxAjCdOfBdGbBpFf@x@TT^Rh@RpAXv@P\\\\L\\\\TZ^Vj@b@nAhBvFlCzHz@`Cj@bAt@rAfA~Bv@tBN`@Bb@@LR`AtAjGTbChA|C\\\\|@J^D`@Dv@@jAWxQMpG@bBXvCJfAc@GwFaC}BuAe@WOEUC\"}}";

        DataJsonConvert objecto = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataJsonConvert>(s);


    }

    public class DataJsonConvert
    {
        public Normal_SLO normal_slo { get; set; }
        public Normal normal { get; set; }
    }

    public class Normal
    {
        public decimal estimated_cost { get; set; }
    }

    public class Normal_SLO
    {
        public decimal estimated_cost { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Desta forma tens o conteúdo do json num objecto.

Comment: Perfeito, valeu!